# WPF design time setting data context for window without error

Tags: wpf, xaml, datacontext

My XAML file is:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Bookstore.Bookstore.ViewModels"
    x:Class="Bookstore.Views.MainWiew" 
    Title="Main Wiew" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid> 
    ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When i run, it's ok. No problem.

But in design time, there is 1 error:

> Datasource file cannot found

I don't want to add datacontext in codebehind.

So, how can i clean error list

**EDIT:**

My MainViewModel.vb file:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Bookstore.Bookstore.Models
Imports Bookstore.Bookstore.Commands
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Input


Namespace Bookstore.ViewModels
Public Class MainViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase

    Sub New()
        LoadBooks()
    End Sub

    Private _currentBook As Book
    Private _books As New ObservableCollection(Of Book)()
    Private _bookstoreRepository As IBookstoreRepository = New BookstoreRepository()
    Private _removeBookCommand As ICommand

#Region "Public Properties"
    Public Property Books() As ObservableCollection(Of Book)
        Get
            Return _books
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Book))

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CurrentBook As Book
        Get
            Return _currentBook
        End Get
        Set(value As Book)
            _currentBook = value
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentBook")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property RemoveBookCommand() As ICommand
        Get
            If _removeBookCommand Is Nothing Then
                _removeBookCommand = New DelegateCommand(Of Book)(AddressOf RemoveBook, AddressOf CanRemoveBook)
            End If
            Return _removeBookCommand
        End Get
        Set(value As ICommand)

        End Set
    End Property
#End Region

#Region "Functions"
    Private Sub LoadBooks()
        For Each book As Book In _bookstoreRepository.GetBooks()
            _books.Add(book)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function CanRemoveBook(book As Book) As Boolean
        Return Books.Count > 0 And Books.Contains(book)
    End Function

    Private Sub RemoveBook(book As Book)
        Books.Remove(book)
        CurrentBook = Nothing
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: what's the code of your `MainViewModel`'s creator?

Comment: @FlashTek , i added my MainViewModel code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode.aspx) method to check for design time, and then return empty or sample data, instead of data loaded from an external source. This will show the sample data in the designer.